# How are Django page templates assigned to each page?

Tags: django, django-templates

I couldn't find this info in the Django docs, but I'm sure it is there, I'm just very new and don't know what terms/etc to search on.

**How are Django page templates assigned to each page?**

I have a login to a Django site, and also SFTP access to the site.  I don't think my Django login is a superuser/full-admin though because the interface seems pretty limited compared to other CMS systems.  I can edit pages, posts and the media library, but I don't see anything that says how each page is assigned a template.

For example, I have this file /mysite/templates/pages/index.html

I know that template is being used for the home page because it has all of the content that is specific to the home page on it, and changes I make show up on the home page.

I tried copying that file to test.html, but when I browse to test.html in my browser, I get a 404 error (I also get that error if I go to index.html).  So there must be something else that maps a template to a page, but I'll be dambed if I can find it.  Will I need more access to the admin area, or can I do something with SFTP?  I also have SSH access but wasn't able to follow any of the steps online to create a new superuser account for me, for Django.

**Edit:** Thanks for both answers, after I work through this I'll accept whichever helped the most.  I do not have a views.py file, but I think it might be using an extra module for this routing, I have this in my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    ("^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
    url("^$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),
    ("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
)
```

Is this "mezzanine" something different which changes the answer (location of views.py or list of views)?

Comment: I found out about Mezzanine and understand now it is a different CMS/addon package for Django, and if I can't figure it out I should ask a question specific to that.  At least I know how Django (core) works, which is a big help.  Thank you.  http://mezzanine.jupo.org/

Comment: For future readers.  If you are using Mezzanine, you can create a new page/form called "test" (for example) and then create a test.html file under pages/templates/ and it will use that template for that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url.py` is the file that maps the urls to methods that return rendered templates. In essence you define the url and a method and when someone goes to that url, that method gets called which returns a HTTP response with the rendered template. This map is called urlpatterns. In the following example when someone goes to yourwebsite/blog then in the blog apps, view.py, page method is called, which will use a template and render that with specific information.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/$', 'blog.views.page'),
    url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>\d+)/$', 'blog.views.page'),
)
```

Have a look at this link.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to include some extra info.  If you could check my edit that would be great -- you've already helped tons, so either way, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. So from your urlpatterns, when you go to yourwebsite.com, it matches the second url pattern, "^$" (which is an empty string after ".com/", and it calls this method to return a HTTP response; mezzanine.pages.views.page. Roughly that is in views.py in mezzanine apps. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Django uses `urls.py` files to map *paths* to *views*. This match is resolved using regular expressions. When a match is found, Django executes the associated view (usually inside `views.py`). The *view* is in charge to render the template required for the path (by finding it on the server's hard disk and loading it).

All aforementioned means that there's no direct association between a url path (i.e www.example.com/path/to/page) and a file on the server's hard disk (i.e /server/path/to/page). It's all performed dynamically by Django's engine when a request comes in.

If you want to know which view is gonna be generated for a specific path, follow the `regex`s at `urls.py` until you find the path you're looking for. Then open the view for that `url` and see inside which `template` it is rendering.

Reading doc's [URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) is a good point to start learning about this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to include some extra info.  If you could check my edit that would be great -- you've already helped tons, so either way, thanks!

Comment: Accepting this answer only because I think it was first.  Both answers were equally helpful.  Now I'm off to learn about Mezzanine, but at least I know where to look now. http://mezzanine.jupo.org/

Comment: @eselk Actually to be fair, deelaws answered first :) I'm glad we could help you anyways.

Comment: OK thanks, I changed the accept.  My screen shows "33 mins ago (edited 28)" on yours and "36" on the other.  Qwirks.